# Remove Parent Category from child category URL

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

How can I edit this:

```
public function getUrlPath($category)
{
    if (in_array($category->getParentId(), [Category::ROOT_CATEGORY_ID, Category::TREE_ROOT_ID])) {
        return '';
    }
    $path = $category->getUrlPath();
    if ($path !== null && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('url_key') && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('parent_id')) {
        return $path;
    }
    $path = $category->getUrlKey();
    if ($path === false) {
        return $category->getUrlPath();
    }
    if ($this->isNeedToGenerateUrlPathForParent($category)) {
        $parentPath = $this->getUrlPath(
            $this->categoryRepository->get($category->getParentId(), $category->getStoreId())
        );
        $path = $parentPath === '' ? $path : $parentPath . '/' . $path;
    }
    return $path;
}
```

such that, the parent category is removed from the child categories' url.

For example:

www.mage.com/c1/c2/c3.html

becomes

www.mage.com/c3.html

Answer (score 1):

We can configure it by **URL Rewrites**

1. Go to Magento 2 Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites
2. Find the path by searching `Request path` column.
3. Remove the cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`.
4. Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.

Example i have modified.

Request path `men/tops-men/tees-men.htm`

Modified path `tees-men.htm`

**Or**

You Can Build category URL path by

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php
```

Modify `getUrlPath($category)` by Magento Plug-in feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean by "Modify getUrlPath($category) by Magento Plug-in feature."?